# Undefined when try to get the value from select

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a problem with ng-select (I am using Angular 10).
I Want To Bind Value Of Dropdown But I Get Undefined
Also Got Problems With Clear Form (Clear Function Is Not Working On This Field)

```js
export class CollectionmanagementComponent implements OnInit {
selectedConnection: any;

onSubmit() {
    this.IsSubmitted = true;
    this.modelValue = 'modal';
    if (this.collectionManagementForm.invalid) {
        this.modelValue = '';
        return;
    }
    if (typeof (this.selectedCollectionsTypes) === 'undefined') {
        this.selectedCollectionsTypes = '';
    }
    let body = {
        ConnectionType: (this.selectedConnection.value) ? this.selectedConnection.value : ''
    };

    if (body.CompanyID) {
        this.accoutingService.updateCollectionsManagement(body, true).subscribe((res) => {
            let data: any = res;
            if (data.response != null && data.response.length > 0) {
                this.restForm();
                this.collectionManagementList = data.response;
                this.showNotificationOnSucess(data);
                this.getAllCollectionsManagement();
                this.ViewEditModalClose.nativeElement.click();
            } else {
                this.showNotification(data);
            }
        }, (err: any) => {
            this.showError(err);
        });
    } else {
        this.accoutingService.addCollectionsManagement(body, true).subscribe((res) => {
            let data: any = res;
            if (data.response !== null && data.responseCode === 200) {
                this.collectionManagementList = data.response;
                this.restForm();
                this.showNotificationOnSucess(data);
                this.getAllCollectionsManagement();
                this.ViewEditModalClose.nativeElement.click();
            } else {
                this.showNotification(data);
            }
        }, (err: any) => {
            this.showError(err);
        });
    }
}

restForm() {
    this.popUpTittle = 'Add';
    this.IsSubmitted = false;
    document.getElementById('btnUpdate').innerText = 'Add';
    this.collectionManagementForm.reset();
    this.clearForm();
}

clearForm() {
    this.collectionManagementForm = this.fb.group({
        ConnectionType: ['']
    });
}
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="theme-label">Connection Type</div>
  <div class="input-group">
<ng-select
  [items]="selectedConnection"
  [closeOnSelect]="true"
  bindValue="id"
  placeholder="Select"
  bindLabel="name"
  formControlName="ConnectionType"
>
  <ng-template let-items="items" let-clear="clear">
    <div class="ng-value" *ngFor="let item of items">
      <ng-option [items]="null" selected>{{item.name}}</ng-option>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</ng-select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post your HTML in the question, not comment. Also share the same data for the options.

Comment: what library from are your ng-select? Check that you're put into the *ngFor the ng-option null. Sure the sintax is wrong